# Django Annotations For Group By Through Another Model

Tags: python, django, orm, annotations, group-by

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to use annotations in the Django ORM to achieve grouping through a model.

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

If my Stores are Los Angeles, Denver, Houston & Atlanta, how do I get a count of
Customers by store using the latest order date?

```
Los Angeles: 25
Denver: 210
Houston: 400
Atlanta: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a ManyToMany field on *either* `Customer` or `Store`, pointing to the other model, with `Order` as the `through` table. For example:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Customer, through=Order)
```

Now you can do:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Store.objects.annotate(Count("orders__customer"))
```

Comment: how does this ensure it's only the latest order_date that's used for the query?

Comment: latest `order_date` means a single Order - is this what you mean ?

Comment: yes..I only want to count the latest order.  If you shopped in Denver last week and Houston this week, I only want to count you for Houston.

Comment: so this query just bit me.  It's not counting only the latest order, instead it's counting ALL orders.